# How to count in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i'm having issues with multidimensional array:

```
 Array
(
    [start] => Array
        (
            [0] => mymail@google.mail
            [1] => antohermail@yahoo.com
            [2] => antohermail@yahoo.com
            [3] => mymail@google.mail
            [4] => 222222@google.mail
            [5] => mymail@google.mail
            [6] => bot001e08@lopbot001
            [7] => antohermail@yahoo.com
            [8] => mymail@google.mail
            [9] => bot001e02@lopbot001.mail
        )

    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => 43
            [1] => 17
            [2] => 15
            [3] => 34
            [4] => 12
            [5] => 37
            [6] => 14
            [7] => 12
            [8] => 33
            [9] => 25
        )

)
```

This multi array has the same number of keys. I would like to show all different emails (start array) and count all values from name array.

So the desired output would be something like that:

mymail@google.mail: 43+34+37+23 = **137**

antohermail@yahoo.com: 17 +15+ 12 = **44**

222222@google.mail: **12**

bot001e08@lopbot001: **14**

bot001e02@lopbot001.mail: **25**

With special function i could get result like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [mymail@google.mail] => 43
                    [antohermail@yahoo.com] => 17
                    [antohermail@yahoo.com] => 15
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [mymail@google.mail] => 34
                    [222222@google.mail] => 12
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [mymail@google.mail] => 37
                    [bot001e08@lopbot001] => 14
                    [222222@google.mail] => 12
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [mymail@google.mail] => 33
                    [bot001e02@lopbot001.mail] => 25
                )

        )

)
```

But i still can not count the values from this multi array

Comment: please share what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this simple loop with nested indexes

```
$mails = array();
        foreach ($data['start'] as $key => $value) {
            $mails[$value]['sum'] = @$mails[$value]['sum'] + $data['name'][$key];
        }
    
 print_r($mails);
```

Result:

```
(
[mymail@google.mail] => Array
    (
        [sum] => 147
    )

[antohermail@yahoo.com] => Array
    (
        [sum] => 44
    )

[222222@google.mail] => Array
    (
        [sum] => 12
    )

[bot001e08@lopbot001] => Array
    (
        [sum] => 14
    )

[bot001e02@lopbot001.mail] => Array
    (
        [sum] => 25
    )
```

)

Comment: Thank you very much. Now i can use [`$ids2 =  array_filter(array_combine(array_keys($mails), array_column($mails, 'sum')));`] to get the correct output!